# web3 equivalent of abi.encodePacked

Tags: solidity, web3js, abi, abiencoderv2

What is the equivalent of abi.encodePacked in web3?

I am trying to generate the equivalent of (solidity)

```
keccak256(abi.encodePacked("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", domainHash, functionHash));
```

with web3, to test from truffle.

So far I know that

keccack256 = web3.utils.soliditySha3

abi.encode = web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters

abi.encodePacked = ????????

Comment: Using `web3.utils.soliditySha3` with the types for each parameter should be equivalent to `keccak256(abi.encodePacked(...))`.

Comment: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/hashing/#utils--solidity-hashing

Answer (score 1):

If you have the contract's ABI you can use [encodeABI](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-encodeabi).

If you don't have the contract's ABI then you can use [web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-abi.html#encodefunctioncall), or combine some of the other functions `from web3.eth.abi.*`.

You can also use [ethereumjs-abi](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi) that implements this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Web3.js has a function called `encodePacked` which should do what you have in mind. I couldn't find any information about it in the [official docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.0/search.html?q=ecodePacked&check_keywords=yes&area=default), but found it while poking around in the [source code](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/blob/63e73bb3f8d4720edcc31441c3b613758ad96cec/packages/web3-utils/src/soliditySha3.js#L253-L267). You can call it with `web3.utils.encodePacked(...args)`.

As you'll see from [the source code](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/blob/63e73bb3f8d4720edcc31441c3b613758ad96cec/packages/web3-utils/src/soliditySha3.js#L182), you can pass it a series of objects in order to specify the types that you intend, e.g.:

```js
web3.utils.encodePacked(
  {value: 42, type: 'uint128'},
  {value: 'trombone', type: 'string'}
);
'0x0000000000000000000000000000002a74726f6d626f6e65'
```

Contrast this with the return value of `encodeParameters`, which is not packed:

```js
web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters(['uint128', 'string'], [42, 'trombone']);
0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000874726f6d626f6e65000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const ethers = require("ethers");
ethers.utils.solidityPack // nodejs equivalent of solidity's abi.encodePacked
```