# What is the output of abi.encodePacked(x,y)?

Tags: abi

What does the `abi.encodePacked("abcdef", "123")` function do and how can I simulate the output?

This function is missing in these projects [web3-eth-abi](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/blob/v1.5.2/packages/web3-eth-abi/src/index.js), [ethereumjs-abi](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi) and when I try to call it in ethfiddle I get an error `ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition. abi.encodePacked`, so I guess I am not doing something right.

related: [web3 equivalent of abi.encodePacked](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/110751/web3-equivalent-of-abi-encodepacked), [How to quickly test a Solidity function?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2835/how-to-quickly-test-a-solidity-function)
resource: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/abi-spec.html#abi-packed-mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `abi.encodePacked("abcdef", "123")` is from solidity.  It packs the parameters "tightly", see the definition here: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/abi-spec.html#non-standard-packed-mode

In this particular case it will return `"abcdef123"`.